# Case VS Multiple Updates

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a statement to update a field if a related table record exists. The query updates for every record. I wasnt sure what the most efficient/best practice way to do this would be. So far i've come up with 2 solutions

**Solution One:** Case Statement

```
UPDATE item
SET IsRestricted = 
    CASE 
        WHEN restriction.Id is null THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END
FROM [dbo].[Item] item
    left join [dbo].[Restriction] restriction
        on restriction.Id = item.Id
```

**Solution Two:** Multiple Update Statements

```
UPDATE item
SET IsRestricted = 1
FROM [dbo].[Restriction] restriction 
    inner join [dbo].[Item] item
        on restriction.Id = item.Id

UPDATE item
SET IsRestricted = 0
FROM [dbo].[Item] item
    left join [dbo].[Restriction] restriction
        on item.Id = restriction.Id
WHERE restriction.Id is null
```

If anyone could help me gauge which i should be using it would be appreciated.

**Note:** Am not sure if this is a duplicate post, so far only similar ones i've seen involve triggers or various other stuff and im not sure if that changes the answer. Also feel free to suggest alternative approaches

Comment: Do you need the IsRestricted column? Wouldn't querying for the presence/absence of restrictions at select time guarantee you always get the right answer?

Comment: Put them both in the same query window, turn on "Include actual execution plan" (ctrl+m), run the batch, observe results :)

Comment: @Damien the flag is there because the database usage is going to be fairly performance intensive and we don't want to have to do lookups at select time. Although I wasn't really looking for a answer specific to my problem as much as a general comparison of the two methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after some performance testing it seems that they are both the same performance wise

Answer (score 1):

As some people have mentioned you can do some performance tests and check out the execution plan for both to work out which might perform the best.

If you are only going to run this statement once I would use the first method as you know you will need to update all records and one statement keeps things nice and simple. If this is going to be run multiple times (i.e when new data is added) then I would use the second solution with an addition to the where clause checking that it isn't already 0/1 when you set it again. This should keep processing to a minimum.